# Past time in german sentences

Tags: grammaticality, past-participle, past

I have this sentence in german :

> Wir haben heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank geschaut und gesehen, dass er leer ist.

In english it probably means something like :

> Today in the morning, we looked into our fridge and saw, that it (is) empty.

Now, in english it should rather be

> we looked into our fridge and saw it was empty (not **is**).

So is the **ist** correct ? Shouldn't it be **war** ?

> Wir haben heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank geschaut und gesehen, dass er leer **war**

Comment: Please note that Kühlschrank is refrigerator, not postbox (Briefkasten)

Comment: Oh, thanks I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no language lawyer but:

Let's look at the two variations of this sentence:

> Wir haben heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank geschaut und gesehen, dass er leer war.

Here, the empty state is in the past which means it was probably refilled in between.

> Wir haben heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank geschaut und gesehen, dass er leer ist.

Here, the empty state is in the present which means it is still empty (probably).

Comment: Seems like reasonable answer, thanks.

Comment: Moment, sollte es aus Gründen der Kongruenz nicht *dass er leer gewesen ist* (Perfekt von *sein*) heißen?

Comment: Das wäre vermutlich die language lawyer Antwort. Umgangssprachlich passt es so auf jeden Fall für mich. Vermutlich ist "war" ohnehin eine der wenigen Formen, die mündlich im Präteritum verwendet wird.

Comment: *... dass er leer **gewesen ist***: Kongruenz, Gleichzeitigkeit zum Hauptsatz. // *... dass er leer **gewesen war***: Vorzeitigkeit. // *... dass er (jetzt) leer **sein würde***: Nachzeitigkeit. // *... dass er leer **ist***: Glaskugel (wir haben damals schon gesehen, dass er jetzt leer ist).

Answer (score 7):

In colloquial German, there is not much of a difference. Many people confuse *Präteritum* and *Perfekt* and even use both tensen within the same sentence. In standard German, there is, basically, the principle of *congruence*: when events occur or states are in the same narrative time, then the tenses should conform.

Let me first give a simpler example:

> - Er *sieht*, dass die Sonne rund *ist*. *(narrative time: Präsens)*
> - Er *sah*, dass die Sonne rund *war*. *(narrative time: Präteritum)*
> - Er *hat gesehen*, dass die Sonne rund *gewesen ist*. *(narrative time: Perfekt)*

However, there is an exception. When a state does not generally change but persists (e.g., the sun is always round and we do not expect it to change its form in the near future), then the *Präsens* can be used, no matter which narrative time is used:

> - Er *sieht* / *sah* / *hat gesehen* *(whichever narrative time)*, dass die Sonne rund *ist* *(Präsens)*.

---

Now, let's look at the original sentences:

> - Wir *haben* heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank *geschaut und gesehen*, dass er leer *war*.

*Haben geschaut* and *haben gesehen* is *Perfekt*, whereas *war* is *Präteritum*. This may be acceptable in colloquial language, but according to the priciple of congruence it shopuld be, dependning on the narrative time, one of these:

> - Wir *schauten* heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank und *sahen*, dass er leer *war*.
> - Wir *haben* heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank *geschaut und gesehen*, dass er leer *gewesen ist*.

The sentence

> - Wir *haben* heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank *geschaut und gesehen*, dass er leer *ist*.

means that the state of the fridge has not changed; it is still empty.

Comment: Still empty möchte ich bestreiten: "Wir haben heute Morgen in unseren Kühlschrank geschaut und gesehen, dass er leer ist. Also haben wir 4 Ananas für heute abend reingelegt."

Comment: @userunknown, in dem Falle wäre *leer ist* (standardsprachlich) ja auch nicht richtig, sondern *leer gewesen ist* (Kongruenz mit *haben geschaut* und *haben gesehen*). Aber danke fürs erneute voreilige Abwerten, obwohl man die Antwort nur so halb gelesen hat.

Comment: Du kannst nicht morgens in den Kühlschrank schauen, und sehen, dass er auch abends noch leer sein wird. Das kannst Du planen, denken, raten und wünschen aber nicht sehen. Du kannst morgens ins Datenbanklog schauen, und sehen, das die Datenbank nachts leer gewesen ist. Das Leersein ist dann im Moment des Schauens abgeschlossen, aus der Perspektive der Vergangenheit liegt die Leere noch weiter in der Vergangenheit. Sie ist zum Zeitpunkt des Schauens vielleicht schon nicht mehr leer.

Comment: @userunknown, aus philosophischer Sicht gebe ich Ihnen recht. Das ist aber bei allen induktiven Schlüssen so, übrigens auch bei der Sonne: nur weil die bei jedem Hinschauen rund *war*, kann ich nicht sicher sein, dass sie es auch morgen noch *ist*. Gleichwohl – um beim Kühlschrank zu bleiben – ist davon auszugehen, dass *leer ist* ausdrückt, dass er zumindest zum Zeitpunkt, da die Aussage getätigt wird, noch leer ist. Das ist ja der Zweck des Präsens, auszudrücken was *ist* und nicht was *war*. Ob es morgen immer noch *ist*, spielt erstmal keine Rolle.

Comment: "Wenn ich nächste Woche, Mittwoch, in das Eisfach schaue, werde ich wohl auch sehen, dass es leer ist. Es ist jetzt nämlich schon kaum noch Eis drin und das Wochenende liegt dazwischen." Ich meine die Sprache transportiert uns in die Vergangenheit oder Zukunft, und aus der schildern wir dann eine gedachte Präsenz. Schriebe ich "werde ich sehen, dass es leer sein wird" klingt für mich nach doppeltem Futur. "Wenn ich in 20 Jahren nachrechne, werde ich drauf kommen, dass die Rente nicht reicht" vs. "nicht reichen wird". Hier fehlt die unmittelbare Sinneswahrnehmung. …

Comment: … Das erste heißt, dass sie wohl schon in 20 Jahren nicht reichen wird, das zweite, dass sie vielleicht erst später nicht reichen wird.